What can be used to replace mpireconfig?
I am trying to compile some legacy code of my PhD research that I did in the early 2000s, mostly for reasons of nostalgia ;-)
The code used mpich. In the version of mpich that I used at the time, there was a tool 'mpireconfig' that converted 'Makefile.in'-files into Makefiles. I have now installed mpich on my MacBook Air M1 (2020) using brew, but unfortunately it seems that mpireconfig is now obsolete.
Is there a way to replace mpireconfig? Makefile.in could also be an output file of autoconf, which uses "*.ac" files (or *.am for automake), but these are not in my source tree. From some old e-mails that I found, I conclude that I must have edited the 'Makefile.in' based on an example, and that mpireconfig converted them to Makefiles.
I hope that somebody here remembers what happened to mpireconfig.
Thanks!
Best wishes,
Roeland
What I have tried so far: Simply using 'make' did not work, because of course the Makefile was configured for an old system; then I tried looking into autoconf and/or automake, and found in my old e-mail conversations that my Makefile.in was the input for a tool called mpireconfig. I tried to install mpireconfig using 'brew install', but it wasn't found. I tried to reinstall mpich, but mpiconfig was not part of it. I tried googling for mpireconfig, and found only manuals from the late 1990s and the early 2000s, which makes me suspect that the tool has been obsolete for long.

Look at the content of a random Makefile.in. The man pages states this is a makefile template, which suggests it could be converted to a regular makefile with a few sed commands. Also if you are using MPI wrappers (e.g. mpicc and friends) you might even be able to simple rename every Makefile.in into Makefile.

You can find historical versions of mpich for download. These tarballs might contain  mpireconfig. Not sure whether that helps you to create a makefile compatible with today's MPI implementations.
